# IBM MQSeries Problem: remote host closes connection when writing message (error 10054)

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am trying to write to an IBM MQSeries host with:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
    queueMessage = new MQMessage();
    queueMessage.WriteString(message);
    queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
    queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();

    queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
}
```

My errorcatch gives me an error however:

> Error in the application

Which doesn't show much of course. So I checked the event log on the server and this showed me the error:

> An error occurred receiving data from
>   stx041774 (192.168.225.51) over
>   TCP/IP. This may be due to a
>   communications failure.
>
> ```
> The return code from the TCP/IP (recv) call was 10054 (X'2746').
> ```
>
> Record these values and tell the
>   systems administrator.

I looked up 10054 and means:

> An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to make this work? Is there perhaps an MQC option I have to set for writing? Because I have no idea what to do with the options, I'm not even sure if this is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue with an option mqc.mqoo_output:

```
queue = qManager.AccessQueue(QueueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
```